# phpMyAdmin Configuration Storage and multiple MySQL-servers

Tags: phpmyadmin, settings

I'm looking into Configuration Storage and trying to find information to see if it supports multiple MySQL-Servers.

Is it possible to use one pmadb database for multiple MySQL-servers?

Can't find anything about it in the docs (I might be blind?) but looking at the tables created makes me believe that it wont work.

Anyone have a link to the information or have an good answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [controlhost](http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html#cfg_Servers_controlhost) and [controlport](http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html#cfg_Servers_controlport) configurations to achieve this.

Comment: But can I have the same controlhost/controlport on two different mysql-servers in the same config.inc.php in pma?